# Writing to two locations not working

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I feel this should be possible but I can only get log4net to go to one appender at a time.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="false">
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\Logs\webclient\Admin.Web\logs\admin.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <!--Database appender-->
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="10" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=(localhost); Database=Error_Logs; Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO [GeneralServiceLog] ([dtLog],[vchLevel],[vchLogger],[vchMessage],[vchException])
     VALUES( @log_date, @log_level, @logger, @message, @ex)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%date{yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff}" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%level" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%logger" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" value="%message" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ex" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
  <Logger>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </Logger>    
</log4net>
```

I want the ERROR level messages to go to the database and DEBUG level messages to go to the text file but all the messaging are just going to file.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure the root logger as follows:

```xml
<root>
   <level value="DEBUG" />
   <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />  
   <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

then you add a filter to the database appender:

```xml
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
   <levelMin value="ERROR" /> 
   <levelMax value="FATAL" />      
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

**Update:**
The problem with your configuration is that you assign the db appender to an unnamed logger and thus your appender in all likelihood never gets called. In log4net you can assign appenders to [loggers](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-5-Using-Logger-Objects.aspx), but not to levels.

Comment: You are correct in that it was never getting called; however, your solution works like a charm.  Also, thanks for that link!  I try to find the answers out there before I wander in here to ask and that page and whole series of tutorials is exactly what I needed (4mos ago *g*)